# tikz - create shaded area inside several paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

I try to create a shaded area inside six paths. I tried to follow
[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580314/) where the package `spath3` had been used.

As you can see in the first picture it works like desired, when I know the explicit coordinates of the paths. However, my real life issue includes a rotation and shift in scope enviroments, which is shown in the second and third example and somehow hinder the incorporation of this method.
Unfortunately, I could only create a similar, not an identical figure for the scope environment example.

Is there any solution how to create a shaded area while using scope environment?
I am not necessarily restricted to the package `spath3`.
Thank you very much.

### Shading - spath3 with exact coordinates

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections,hobby}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \getComponentOf \clist_item:Nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{ % from texexchange: transform defined coordinates in TikZ
    c/.style={every coordinate/.try}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, every node/.style={scale=10}, scale=13]
 
     \draw[spath/save=orange, orange] (3,1)  -- (6,4) ;
     \draw[spath/save=blue, blue] (1,4) -- (4,1) ;
     \draw[spath/save=red, red] (0.5,2.5)  --  (3.5,6) ;    
     \draw[spath/save=lime, lime] (2,2)  --  (2,5) ;
     \draw[spath/save=green, green] (6,2.6)  --  (2.5,6) ;
     \draw[spath/save=yellow, yellow] (5,2.6) --  (5,4) ;
     \draw[spath/save=lime, lime] (2,2)  -- (2,5) ;
 
     \tikzset{
      spath/split at intersections={lime}{red},
      spath/split at intersections={lime}{blue},
      spath/split at intersections={blue}{orange},
      spath/split at intersections={orange}{yellow},
      spath/split at intersections={yellow}{green},
      spath/split at intersections={green}{red},
      spath/get components of={lime}\limecpts,
      spath/get components of={red}\redcpts,
      spath/get components of={blue}\bluecpts,
      spath/get components of={orange}\orangecpts,
      spath/get components of={yellow}\yellowcpts,
      spath/get components of={green}\greencpts,
      }

      \fill[
      orange,
      spath/restore=\getComponentOf\orangecpts{2}
      ]
      [
      spath/append=\getComponentOf\yellowcpts{2},
      spath/append=\getComponentOf\greencpts{2},
      spath/append reverse=\getComponentOf\redcpts{2},
      spath/append reverse =\getComponentOf\limecpts{2},
      spath/append=\getComponentOf\bluecpts{2},
      ]
      ;

      %% Useful for figuring out which components to use and what direction they go in
      \foreach \pth/\cpts in {lime/\limecpts,red/\redcpts,blue/\bluecpts,orange/\orangecpts,yellow/\yellowcpts,green/\greencpts}
      {
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\cpts\cpts
      \foreach[count=\k] \cpt in \cpts
      {
      \node[font=\tiny] at (spath cs:{\cpt} .5) {\pth-\k};
      \node[transform shape, spath/transform to=\cpt{.8}, font=\tiny] {>};
      } 
      }


      \filldraw[green] (3.2,3) to[closed,curve through={(3.3,4)}] (3.5,3) ;

    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: spath3 example]

### No attempt to create a shaded area with scope environments

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections,hobby}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \getComponentOf \clist_item:Nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{ % from texexchange: transform defined coordinates in TikZ
    c/.style={every coordinate/.try}
}


\begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale = 10]
   
    \draw[yellow, name path=yellow]  (2,0)  -- (0,-5)  ;
    \draw[lime,name path=lime] (-1,-1) -- (-3,-5) ;
                
    \begin{scope}[every coordinate/.style={shift={(-3,-4)}, rotate={(140)}}]
    \draw[red, name path=red]  ([c]1,2) -- ([c]0,-4) ;
    \draw[orange,name path=orange] ([c]-1,2)  -- ([c]-3,-4) ;
    \end{scope}
                
    \begin{scope}[every coordinate/.style={shift={(-1,-4)}, rotate={(240)}}]
    \draw[blue, name path=blue]  ([c]2,2)  -- ([c]0,-2) ;
    \draw[green,name path=green] ([c]-1,2) -- ([c]-3,-2) ;
    \end{scope}
  
        \filldraw[green] (-1,-3) to[closed,curve through={(-0.5,-2.5)}] (-0.2,-3) ;

  
  \end{tikzpicture}
 

\end{document}
```

[image: scope example]

### Attempt to create a shaded area with scope environments

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections,hobby}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \getComponentOf \clist_item:Nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{ % from texexchange: transform defined coordinates in TikZ
    c/.style={every coordinate/.try}
}


\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale = 10]

    \draw[yellow, spath/save=yellow]  (2,0)  -- (0,-5)  ;
    \draw[lime,spath/save=lime] (-1,-1) -- (-3,-5) ;

    \begin{scope}[every coordinate/.style={shift={(-3,-4)}, rotate={(140)}}]
    \draw[red, spath/save=red]  ([c]1,2) -- ([c]0,-4) ;
    \draw[orange,spath/save=orange] ([c]-1,2)  -- ([c]-3,-4) ;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[every coordinate/.style={shift={(-1,-4)}, rotate={(240)}}]
    \draw[blue, spath/save=blue]  ([c]2,2)  -- [c]0,-2) ;
    \draw[green,spath/save=green] ([c]-1,2) -- ([c]-3,-2) ;
    \end{scope}


  \tikzset{
      spath/split at intersections={lime}{red},
      spath/split at intersections={lime}{blue},
      spath/split at intersections={blue}{orange},
      spath/split at intersections={orange}{yellow},
      spath/split at intersections={yellow}{green},
      spath/split at intersections={green}{red},
      spath/get components of={lime}\limecpts,
      spath/get components of={red}\redcpts,
      spath/get components of={blue}\bluecpts,
      spath/get components of={orange}\orangecpts,
      spath/get components of={yellow}\yellowcpts,
      spath/get components of={green}\greencpts
      }

      \fill[
        orange,
        spath/restore=\getComponentOf\orangecpts{2}
      ]
      [
        spath/append=\getComponentOf\yellowcpts{2},
        spath/append=\getComponentOf\greencpts{2},
        spath/append reverse=\getComponentOf\redcpts{2},
        spath/append reverse =\getComponentOf\limecpts{2},
        spath/append=\getComponentOf\bluecpts{2}
      ]
      ;



      %% Useful for figuring out which components to use and what direction they go in
    \foreach \pth/\cpts in {lime/\limecpts,red/\redcpts,blue/\bluecpts,orange/\orangecpts,yellow/\yellowcpts,green/\greencpts}
    {
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\cpts\cpts
      \foreach[count=\k] \cpt in \cpts
      {
        \node[font=\tiny] at (spath cs:{\cpt} .5) {\pth-\k};
        \node[transform shape, spath/transform to=\cpt{.8}, font=\tiny] {>};
      }
    }


\filldraw[green] (-1,-3) to[closed,curve through={(-0.5,-2.5)}] (-0.2,-3) ;

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

This fails to compilate.

#### Log output

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.7.7)  9 JUL 2022 11:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-07-04>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count186
\c@sapage=\count187

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)

[Some omissions due to space limit.]


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 19.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__dim_eval_end: 
l.50       }
            
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \__dim_eval_end: 
l.50       }
            
End of file on the terminal!

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 24193 strings out of 478024
 648019 string characters out of 5838710
 1020163 words of memory out of 5000000
 42291 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 99i,2n,108p,717b,609s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \__dim_eval_end: 
l.50       }
            
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on document.log.

Timeout/Error status: 1 [pdflatex][document]
```

Comment: Scopes create TeX groups so you need to get your spath definitions out of those groups to use them in your intersections.  Simplest way is to use the `global` version of the save command, which - if I remember right - is `spath/save global`

Comment: Thank you once again! That was the solution. Your knowledge is really impressive.

Comment: Well, I probably do know more than most about the spath3 package ...

Comment: PS if that worked and has fixed it, you should consider posting an answer to your question with the working code.

Comment: That is certainly an understatement, not only as package creator. :-) I meant in general. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

All thanks to the modest Andrew!

(I have just realized that I twisted the code snippet in the original post, as I had too many versions of it. Therefore the above code will not work without correcting the direction of the paths. Sorry.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections,hobby}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \getComponentOf \clist_item:Nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{ % from texexchange: transform defined coordinates in TikZ
    c/.style={every coordinate/.try}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, every node/.style={scale=10}, scale=13]

    \draw[yellow, spath/save global=yellow]  (2,0)  -- (0,-5)  ;
    \draw[lime,spath/save global=lime] (-1,-1) -- (-3,-5) ;

    \begin{scope}[every coordinate/.style={shift={(-3,-4)}, rotate={(140)}}]
    \draw[red, spath/save global=red]  ([c]1,2) -- ([c]0,-4) ;
    \draw[orange,spath/save global=orange] ([c]-1,2)  -- ([c]-3,-4) ;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[every coordinate/.style={shift={(-1,-4)}, rotate={(240)}}]
    \draw[blue, spath/save global=blue]  ([c]2,2)  -- ([c]0,-2) ;
    \draw[green,spath/save global=green] ([c]-1,2) -- ([c]-3,-2) ;
    \end{scope}


  \tikzset{
      spath/split at intersections={lime}{red},
      spath/split at intersections={lime}{blue},
      spath/split at intersections={blue}{orange},
      spath/split at intersections={orange}{yellow},
      spath/split at intersections={yellow}{green},
      spath/split at intersections={green}{red},
      spath/get components of={lime}\limecpts,
      spath/get components of={red}\redcpts,
      spath/get components of={blue}\bluecpts,
      spath/get components of={orange}\orangecpts,
      spath/get components of={yellow}\yellowcpts,
      spath/get components of={green}\greencpts
      }

      \fill[
        orange,
        spath/restore=\getComponentOf\orangecpts{2}
      ]
      [
        spath/append reverse=\getComponentOf\yellowcpts{2},
        spath/append=\getComponentOf\greencpts{2},
        spath/append reverse=\getComponentOf\redcpts{2},
        spath/append =\getComponentOf\limecpts{2},
        spath/append reverse=\getComponentOf\bluecpts{2}
      ]
      ;



 
\filldraw[green] (-1,-3) to[closed,curve through={(-0.5,-2.5)}] (-0.2,-3) ;

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]